# Why is my table rendering always the same email?

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a table with material UI and i want to render the employee data.

My employees have a user property that contains a user id associated to a user. And the user contains the email.

I have the following component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import EnhancedTable from '../components/UI/EnhancedTable';
import { fetchEmployees } from '../slices/employeeSlice';
import { fetchUsers } from '../slices/userSlice';
import "../styles/pages/EmployeesData.css";

const EmployeesData = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { employees, loading, error } = useSelector(state => state.employees);
  const { users } = useSelector(state => state.users);
  console.log(users);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchEmployees());
    dispatch(fetchUsers());
    
  }, [dispatch]);

  if (loading) {
    return <div>Cargando empleados...</div>;
  }

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error al cargar los empleados: {error}</div>;
  }


  return (
    <section className='employees__data'>
      <h2>Lista de Empleados</h2>
      <EnhancedTable employees={employees} users={users} />
    </section>
  );
};

export default EmployeesData;
```

I am sending all the employees and all the users that i fetched to the component where i render my table

```
EnhancedTableToolbar.propTypes = {
  numSelected: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};

export default function EnhancedTable({ employees, users }) {
  const [order, setOrder] = useState("asc");
  const [orderBy, setOrderBy] = useState("name");
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  const [dense, setDense] = useState(false);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(5);
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);



  useEffect(() => {
    if (employees.length > 0) {
      setRows(
        employees.map((item) =>
          createData(
            item.name,
            item.lastName,
            users.find((user) => user.id ===item.id).email,
            item._id,
            item.type,
            item.sales
          )
        )
      );
    }
  }, [employees, users]);
```

Why is it always rendering me the first email for all the rows and not the associated email to the user id?

Comment: Show the createData code, please

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, your approach is incorrect.

find definition : `Returns the value of the first element in the array where predicate is true, and undefined otherwise.`

I imagine your users & employees objects and createData function looks like the following: (both objects are hardcoded for test)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const users = [
  { _id: 1, email: "user1@example.com" },
  { _id: 2, email: "user2@example.com" },
  { _id: 3, email: "user3@example.com" }
]

const employees = [
  {
      name: "John",
      lastName: "Doe",
      _id: 1,
      type: "Customer",
      sales: 10
  },
  {
      name: "Alice",
      lastName: "Smith",
      _id: 2,
      type: "Employee",
      sales: 5
  },
  {
      name: "Bob",
      lastName: "Johnson",
      _id: 2,
      type: "Customer",
      sales: 8
  }
]
const EnhancedTable = () => {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (employees.length > 0) {
      setRows(
        employees.map((item) =>
          createData(
            item.name,
            item.lastName,
            users.find((user) => user.id === item.id).email,
            item._id,
            item.type,
            item.sales
          )
        )
      );
    }
  }, [employees, users]);

  const createData = (name,lastName, email, _id,type,sales)=> {
    console.log(email)
    return {}
  }

  return (
    <div></div>
  );
}

export default EnhancedTable;
```

`users.find((user) => user.id === item.id)` this statement always becomes `undefined` and returns the first element of the array according to find function definition (because you are comparing `id` property instead of `_id`).

if you change that line to `users.find((user) => user._id === item._id)?.email`
You can get the correct answer.

The issue in the code is that you are going to check for existing properties in the object. I assumed both objects have property called `_id`.

I think this would help